# Wpf app crashing - Faulting module name coreclr.dll version: 4.700.20.47201

Tags: wpf, .net-core, coreclr

I have WPF application on .netcore 3.1 packed in appx package and installed from the package. Sometimes (one on several dozen starts) it crashes on startup with errors in EventViewer:

first error entry:

```
Application: MyApp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.47201
.NET Core Version: 3.1.9
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFE0C06FF20 (00007FFE0C050000) with exit code 80131506.
```

next error entry:

```
Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5f6b3998
Faulting module name: coreclr.dll, version: 4.700.20.47201, time stamp: 0x5f6a7a28
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000001ff20
Faulting process id: 0x5920
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6ca611262b108
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MyPublisher.MyApp_1.1.166.0_x64__k3e1zgp7z7sz2\MyApp\MyApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MyPublisher.MyApp_1.1.166.0_x64__k3e1zgp7z7sz2\MyApp\coreclr.dll
Report Id: 0b0ae2f1-0a4c-439a-a4cd-4700425d3f41
Faulting package full name: MyPublisher.MyApp_1.1.166.0_x64__k3e1zgp7z7sz2
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to work through this problem?

Comment: Do you found the reason for the error? I have a similar one.

Comment: Any breakthrough, I am stuck with this issue too

Comment: @IkelieCyril Check my answer, please.

Comment: @MartinBraun I used the setup extension on vs 2019 to build an installer for the application. It gets installed on the specified OS versions without crashing.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with .NET 5.0 and [I filed a report](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/5615), since I believe this is related.

For now, I simply uncheck "Produce single file" in the publishing settings to get rid of this error. This fixes the error for me, but I end up with a lot of files in the publishing directory. This is a little bit unfulfilling, but I can continue for now.

Comment: I used the setup extension on vs 2019 to build an installer for the application. It gets installed on the specified OS versions without crashing.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I require a single file though

Comment: @Julien I was able to get a single file using the setup extension available for visual studio. See my comment above.

Answer (score -1):

Use a setup project to build an installer for the application. This process will bundle the application in a setup.exe which is more portable and does not crash.